# Android: Passing 2 Input Parameters Through A Method Activated By A View

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a method that is activated when another method gives it an int, and at the same time, the method can also be activated by a view.

Here is the top line of the method and where in Java the method is called:

```
checkNum(theNumber, null);
public void checkNum (int num, View view){
```

I tried using "onClick" in the xml for a button, but checkNum did not appear as a suggestion and the app crashed when I ran it. How can I fix this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could also post error that you are getting. I think that the problem is that onClick method can have only one parameter (a View that has been clicked)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `onClick` attribute in XML, the correct signature to use is

```
public void checkNum (View view)
```

If you want to pass in a other parameters, I suggest that you set it in Java code.

Add a click listener to your `button` this way:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something when the button is clicked
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So sorry to ask, but how exactly can I do this?

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by *"is activated by a view"* ? Like, by a click ?

Comment: Ya, like with a button